# Rendering a google map with multiple markers with custom field data

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have been trying to render a new google map with multiple markers with a data i extracted from custom fields from a specific pages.

the custom field i am using is Google Map,
here is the code (notice it is written in html syntax (wordpress template).

i am using google map api and thier recommanded JS.
the costum field i am calling is "**locationMap**", i am getting selecting what pages i wanna include in my map on the "category-children" field - object post field, from there extracting the gps/location data of each of the pages i included there.

thanks in advance,

here is my code:

```
<?php $categories = get_field("category-children"); if ($categories) : ?>    
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="acf-map">
                <?php foreach( $categories as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
                <?php $location = the_field('locationMap',$post->ID);?>
                <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="
    <?php echo $location['lng']; ?>">
                    <h4><?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?></h4>
                    <p class="address">
                        <?php echo $location['address']; ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution,

the problem was with the "the_field", i got the data as echo to the $, changed it from:

```
<?php $location = the_field('locationMap',$post->ID);?>
```

to:

```
<?php $location = get_field('locationMap',$post->ID);?>
```

and it worked.